# php float variable problems

Tags: php, floating-point

I have:

```
$newscore = $score*.3
```

Now the `$newscore` when dumped shows:

```
(float)0.6 (float)-0.6
```

when echoed:

```
0.6-0.6
```

Firstly how can I make the var value just `0.6` as the `$score` is only positive `2`? Is there a convert to string or something like that.

Secondly the stored value in `$newscore` does not seem to pass to my SQL INSERT function which is setup using placeholder method `%d $newscore`.

Comment: Show us your code and we'll tell you what's wrong with it. `$newscore = $score*.3` will store `0.6` into `$newscore` if `$score` is `2` or `"2"`.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/TUfQzF works here as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me, it returns `double(0.6)`

```
$score = 2;
$newscore = $score * 0.3;

var_dump($newscore);
```

As for your second question, you should use `%f` instead of `%d` when using decimal numbers